# Can $x$ values ​be equal in a regression function?

Tags: regression

I want to know if the values of $x$ in a regression function, especially in the field of econometrics, can have the same values, for example the number 3.

And in that case, we will still have a regression function???

I need to prove this matter in the form of a formula and a concept.

Comment: Regression, broadly speaking, fits a curve to a bunch of points without expecting it to pass exactly through *any* of those points.  Why, then, would there be any problem if some of those points happened to be positioned vertically with respect to one another?

Answer (score 3):

There is no inherent problem in repeated values of any predictor $x$ in regression, so long as there are at least two distinct values of that predictor present in the data. If a predictor were always 3, or always 42, or whatever, it is useless as a predictor and will automatically be ignored by good regression code.

For example, such a predictor could be binary with values 0 and 1 (a.k.a. e.g. dummy, indicator, Boolean, logical, quantal, zero-one). In that circumstance not only are repeated values of 0 and 1 allowed; they are in a strong sense expected.

Econometrics is not special here, as in most respects, as compared with other applications of regression.

I don't see that you need to prove this or what else can be said formally. .